# How erlang returns exit status to linux

Tags: linux, ssh, erlang, erlang-shell, erlang-ports

When I tried to ssh to the IP in Linux through erlang.
SSH was getting successful, but while trying to check the exit status of the ssh
Its showing 255, which was treated as a failure case.

But when i tried to ssh to the IP without using erlang.
Its returning 0 in the success case.

Can you please let me know how erlang sends the exit status to linux.
I just want to know which files were responsible in sending the exit status to the linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post how did you try to do it.

Comment: You need to provide more details about how you're running your Erlang application. Are you running it from a shell command, or from an escript, or through an OTP release, or some other way?

Comment: im running in linux shell.
Our product was included with otp.
we are executing this command from linux shell.

Comment: @JayanthMandavilli: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).